# Cordova Android: handling back button

Tags: android, cordova

`document.addEventListener ('backbutton', function (evt) {
 if (x) return // Proceed normally.
 // Do stuff.
})`

Adding the back button event listener overrides all the default behavior. (HTML5 History pop listener)

But, that's not what I want. I want the back button to potentially not fire (i.e.: something like `evt.preventDefault`), allowing the HTML5 History pop event to run. HELP!

Comment: I suppose you should ask this as a feature request to cordova developers.

Answer (score 0):

it will override the default one. as in the documentation there is no need to prevent the default behavior.
But since in Cordova, "Default behavior" Is just exiting the app you can make it do the same by:

```
if (x) navigator.app.exitApp();
```

Comment: I don't think you quite got my problem... adding the back button event listener does override the (HTML5 History pop listener) default behavior, but I do not want it to. I wanted to run a function when the back button is pressed via the Cordova ``backbutton`` event listener, without Cordova overriding the default HTML5 History behavior.

Comment: Oh, ``backbutton`` event is fired when the user presses the ``android back button`` (soft or hard key at the bottom left of the phone), so if I understood you want this button to do something if a condition met and do it's default behavior otherwise? If that's true I think (not sure though since normally you'd have a single page app with fake pages in Cordova) that backbutton default behavior in Cordova is exiting the app, but in any case have you tried to go back through javascript like:

``if(x) window.history.back();``

Comment: Also it looks like there is a problem with these event-listeners, so except if I did something wrong or in case if it is happening just to me I wouldn't count on them so much, look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873355/cordova-android-back-button-event-doesnt-fire

Comment: Hmm, not sure that window.history.back() will get the pop event listeners to run, but worth a try.