# Cordova Android Back button event doesnt fire

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mobile

It just doesn't fire! i tried everything. the funny thing is that the Menu button works fine:

```
//...
//if (isDevice) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
//}
//...
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
    //document.addEventListener("searchbutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown() {
    alert('Doesnt work!');
}
function onMenuKeyDown() {
    alert('Works just fine!');
}
```

And although I'm in doubt now but I believe it was working earlier this week! :/
Any idea what's going on? is it a bug?
I appreciate your help in advance,
thx, mim

---

cordova -v: 4.3.0

Tested on: Android 4.2.2

Comment: try to debug through logcat in eclipse

Comment: I'm guessing may be there is a javascript error. how you're finding this isDevice!!

Comment: What is isDevice? What version of cordova you are using? If you can give these info I will try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi all and thx for your messages,
Usage of isDevice is to be able to debug as much as possible in the browser and it works with no problem and as I said the menu button works fine (which uses the same process) but anyway I use isDevice Just during the preproduction time and I removed it now and it still doesn't work.
I will update the question with all the information you asked in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Cordova, Android SDK and Build tools resolved the problem completely! I guess the way cordova Build works is a bit messy! looks like it pulls some repositories everytime regardless of their compatibility to other dependencies (even its own version)

Although that problem (and also another issue relating to opening Google play store links with google play store app and not browser or in-app browser) are solved now again, but updating everything introduced a new and weird problem! now I cant do any AJAX calls! any idea?!

### PS:

Just for record, after update you have to remove and add android platform otherwise you'll get a lot of bizarre build fails! :))

### PS2

Now that **back btn** works, the **menu button** does not trigger any event! so confused! :/